# Firestore: Get parameters from query

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I am using Java Admin SDK to run some queries to my Firestore db.

It looks like this:

```
ApiFuture<QuerySnapshot> future = query.get();
```

I get this [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query) `query` object from another method and I would like to check if a `limit` is set before executing it. I can't find a way to do that. In clientcode in dart there is a method called `parameters` that lists the set query-params. But I can't find an equivalent in Java. Anyone has an idea how to check if a limit is already set?

Thanks!

Comment: The link you shared is regarding the android documentation. Are you using the proper SDK for your project? 


[Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/database/Query#limitToFirst(int)) is the link for de Java Admin SDK, specifically for the limit method there are two varieties limitToFirst and limitToLast, the only query parameter they receive is the int for the amount you want to show.

What are you trying to accomplish?